# Have a more consistent look and feel with IE8+, Chrome, Firefox

Tags: css

I'm having problems getting some of the CSS3 properties such as rounded corners on buttons to show up in my IE 8 browser.  The rounded corners appear fine in IE9+, Firefox, and Chrome.  I'm utilizing some of the bootstrap classes in my MVC 4 Web Application. Is there any way to have more consistent styling with older versions of IE such as IE 8?  I have heard of CSS3 Pie but want to see if there are other alternatives available. Can anyone offer any suggestions?  Here is a list of the include files in my application:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="description" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />


    @*----------------------------JQUERY------------------------------------*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.json-2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    @*----------------------------Modernizr------------------------------------*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>


    @*----------------------------Bootstrap------------------------------------*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    @*-----------------------Bootstrap Form Helpser----------------------------*@
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.flags.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-formhelpers.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.en_US.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-datepicker.en_US.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-fonts.codes.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-fontsizes.codes.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-fontsizes.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-googlefonts.codes.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-googlefonts.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-languages.codes.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-languages.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-selectbox.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-states.en_US.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-states.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-timepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-timezones.codes.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-formhelpers-timezones.js"></script>


    @*----------------------------Font Awesome----------------------------------*@
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />



    @*----------------------------Moment----------------------------------*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>


    @*----------------------------Site Specific----------------------------------*@
    <link href="~/Content/UrgentCareWaitWeb.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/UrgentCareWeb.js"></script>






</head>
```

Comment: best to let it degrade for older browsers such as IE8, use CSS3PIE is a performance hit and if you have complex nav with position absolute and whatnot, it will cause style conflicts. I tried it doing my curent responsive website project and it was so bad that we got rid of it

Comment: if you want CSS rounded corners in IE8, there is no better solution than CSS3Pie. There are other scripts available, but CSS3Pie is the best among them by some distance. As @Huangism says, it does have a performance implication (although given how many other JS files you're including, you obviously don't have an issue with that).